# how to show Soft deleted items in laravel?

Tags: laravel, lazy-loading

i have an order that belongs to many products(pivot table) and an invoice  that belongs to order! i used soft delete to display products in my order (it works) and now i want to display those trashed items in my invoice! how can i achieve this? In order model i have this :

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','order_product','ord_id','prod_id')->withPivot('prod_quantity','discount')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and in invoice controller i have this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::with('order.products')->find($id);
    
    return response()->json([
        'error' => false,
        'invoice' => $invoice,
    ],200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `withTrashed()`

```
public function show($id)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::withTrashed()
          ->with('order.products')
          -->find($id);
    
    return response()->json([
        'error' => false,
        'invoice' => $invoice,
    ],200);
}
```

EDIT

Ensure your model uses soft delete trait.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: Call to undefined method App\\Invoice::withTrashed()

Comment: "message": "Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::withTrashed()",
    "exception": "BadMethodCallException",

Comment: Do you have soft delete trait in model?

Comment: I just added it now ! But it doesn't work! Only products that are not deleted are showing

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I guess onlyTrashed() should be used as question is asking to only show those which are soft deleted.

Comment: I want to display products that are trashed and products that are not trashed actually